# Neo4j cannot use neo4j-admin import tool since "Directory already contains a database"

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases

When I use `neo4j-admin import` to import CSV format files to Neo4j, it warns `Directory '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db' already contains a database`. I stop the neo4j and then delete `graph.db` by `rm -rf ./graph.db`. However, the `graph.db` is created automatically at once after deleting and thus the import fails again. How to delete the `graph.db` database thoroughly and accomplish the import process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neo4j-admin import` should be run on an offline database. You shouldn't be starting up the db after you delete the graph.db folder, since that's probably how the graph.db is being recreated.

Comment: sorry for delay comment. I have tried to stop neo4j and its service, it is successful. really appreciate your help.